# Issue in binding nested json object

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new in Angular 6. I am getting error ("ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'Phone.HomePhone'")
when I am trying to bind json data in template.

Please let me know where is the issue in blow code

Component:-

```
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private 
             router: Router, private patientService: 
             PatientService) { }
 addForm: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit() {
   this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   PatientId: ['', Validators.required],
   FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
   LastName: ['', Validators.required],
   Phone:{ HomePhone:[''], WorkPhone:[''], 
           CellPhone:['']}
 });
}
```

Template Code :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2 class="text-center">Add Patient</h2>
<form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input formControlName="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="HomePhone">Home Phone:</label>
  <input formControlName="Phone.HomePhone" placeholder="Home Phone" name="Phone.HomePhone" class="form-control" id="Phone.HomePhone">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a inner form group for `phone`

```
LastName: ['', Validators.required],
Phone: this.formBuilder.group({ 
  HomePhone:['6767'],  
   WorkPhone:[''], 
   CellPhone:['']
})
```

then add the new form group in the html

```
<div class="form-group" formGroupName="Phone"> 
  <input formControlName="HomePhone" placeholder="Home Phone"  class="form-control"  >
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwo77j?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: can we simply write formControl() instead of [ ' ' ] for nested values

Answer (score 0):

> Actual issue is the way you are trying to access the nested FormControl. To implement nested control, you need to make the couple of changes in your code.

1. Convert Phone to `FormGroup` in ts file
2. Add `formGroupName` in html

### ts

```
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private 
             router: Router, private patientService: 
             PatientService) { }
 addForm: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit() {
   this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   PatientId: ['', Validators.required],
   FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
   LastName: ['', Validators.required],
   Phone:this.formBuilder.group({ HomePhone:[''], WorkPhone:[''], 
           CellPhone:['']})
 });
}
```

### html

```
<input formControlName="HomePhone" placeholder="Home Phone" name="HomePhone" class="form-control" id="HomePhone">


<div class="col-md-6">
<h2 class="text-center">Add Patient</h2>
<form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input formControlName="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
</div>

<div class="form-group" formGroupName="Phone">
  <label for="HomePhone">Home Phone:</label>
  <input formControlName="HomePhone" placeholder="Home Phone" name="HomePhone" class="form-control" id="HomePhone">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first create your formGroup as below :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   PatientId: ['', Validators.required],
   FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
   LastName: ['', Validators.required],
   Phone: this.formBuilder.group({ HomePhone:[''], WorkPhone:[''], 
           CellPhone:['']})
 });
}
```

then in your html part you can call it like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="HomePhone">Home Phone:</label>
  <input [formControl]="addForm.controls['Phone'].controls['HomePhone']" placeholder="Home Phone" name="Phone.HomePhone" class="form-control" id="Phone.HomePhone">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Tried but i am getting error. "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"

Comment: i usually use it to manage my nested form groups , be sure please that the phone control was correctly created  : `Phone: this.formBuilder.group({ HomePhone:[''], WorkPhone:[''], 
           CellPhone:['']})` , 
Regards,